# Create dict from local variables like JavaScript `{ var1, var2, ...}` with Python

Tags: python, dictionary

- For JavaScript, object can be created by

```
a=1;
obj={ a }  // JSON.stringify(obj) == '{"a":1}'
```

this make the `obj` has key `a` and its value is `1`

- For Python code is:

```
a = 1
obj = { 'a': a }
```

Is it possible to create a function or class that make code like this?

```
a = 1
obj = func_or_class(a)  # obj == {'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the way you need to work with the data, really. Your methods above are sound, especially the dict comprehension. So other than the old-fashioned way:

`{"key": "value", ... }`

I'd say you're doing it right. If you have a specific example, you can edit your question and I will try to work off that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Example has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3
my_dict = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k.startswith('var')}
```

or

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
var3 = 3
var4 = "abc"
my_dict = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, str)}
```

Comment: not only 'var1', 'var2'...there may be 'foo1', 'foo2', 'something-else'...

Comment: If the types of the value are similar? For example, they are all 'int' or 'string' or something else... you can code  "if isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, str)" or "if isinstance(v, something else)"

Comment: data: Dict[str, Any]

Answer (score 0):

Since all the built-in members of `locals()` starts and ends with `__`, you can filter them out by these prefix and suffix. In addition, you can filter out functions by using `callable`:

For example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
output = {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if not (k.startswith("__") and k.endswith("__")) and not callable(v)}
print(output) # output: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot, the following code is nearly what I want:

```
class LocalDict(dict):
    def __new__(cls, spaces, attrs):
         return {k: v for k, v in spaces.items() if k in attrs.split()}

def foo():
    a = 1
    b = c = 2
    my_dict = LocalDict(locals(), 'a b c')
    return my_dict

print(foo())  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
```

And I wonder whether there is some way that I don't need to pass `locals` to the `LocalDict` class.